# white space in legends while (using breaks argument) plotting rasterLayer with plot() in R

Tags: r, plot, legend, whitespace

I am plotting a RasterLayer with `plot()` function.

While using `breaks=c(seq(-0.1:0.4,0.45,0.1))`. There are whitespace in up and down area of a legend. if I am not using breaks. Legend is automatically created without whitespace. But label is not what I want to plot.

Here is the part of the code:

```
bb_poly<- readOGR("ne_50m_wgs84_bounding_box.shp")
bb_poly<- spTransform(bb_poly,crs)
bb_poly

pallete <- brewer.pal(7,"YlGn")
lnd<- c(seq(-0.1:0.4,0.45,0.1))

Land_JUNE <- plot(Land_JUNE, breaks=lnd,col= pallete, axes=F, frame.plot=FALSE, box = FALSE, boundary.plot=FALSE, bty="n", legend.args = list(text='Land_JUNE'))
plot(bb_poly, main="IN JUNE",add=T)
plot(coastline ,add=T)
```

link of the image
[Link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16mumpilAiC-scNZrJwUyww84Pb8ZAJdi/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

I have used `zlim = c(-0.1,0.45,0.1)` inside plot function which creates a good legend without any space.

```
Land_JUNE <-
  plot(
   Land_JUNE,
   breaks = lnd,
   col = pallete,
   axes = FALSE,
   frame.plot = FALSE,
   zlim = c(-0.1,0.45,0.1),
   box = FALSE,
   boundary.plot = FALSE,
   bty = "n",
   legend.args = list(text='Land_JUNE')
)
```